# How to pass variables to a Kubernetes YAML file from Ansible?

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I am to trying to pass variables to kubernetes YAML file from Ansible but somehow values are not being populated.

Here is my playbook:

```
- hosts: master
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    logstash_port: 5044
  tasks:
   - name: Creating kubernetes pod
     command: kubectl create -f logstash.yml
```

`logstash.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata: logstash
spec:
  containers:
  - name: logstash
    image: logstash
    ports:
      - containerPort: {{ logstash_port }}
```

Is there a better way to pass arguments to Kubernetes YAML file that is being invoked using command task?

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do has no chance of working. Kubernetes (the `kubectl` command) has **nothing** to do with Jinja2 syntax, which you try to use in the `logstash.yml`, and it has no access to Ansible objects (for multiple reasons).

---

Instead, use [`k8s_raw` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_raw_module.html) to manage Kubernetes objects.

You can include Kubernetes' manifest directly in the `definition` declaration and there you can use Jinja2 templates:

```
- k8s_raw:
    state: present
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Pod
      metadata: logstash
      spec:
        containers:
          - name: logstash
            image: logstash
            ports:
              - containerPort: "{{ logstash_port }}"
```

Or you can leave your `logstash.yml` as is, and feed it using the template lookup plugin:

```
- k8s_raw:
    state: present
    definition: "{{ lookup('template', 'path/to/logstash.yml') | from_yaml }}"
```

<sub>Notice if you used Jinja2 template directly in Ansible code, you must quote it. It's not necessary with the template plugin.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried to install k8s_raw but did not find clear instructions on how to install k8s_raw module in ansible.

Comment: You don't need to install anything. It is included in Ansible since version 2.5.

Comment: Updated the ansible version to 2.5.3. 

<code>ansible --version
ansible 2.5.3
config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
executable location = /bin/ansible
python version = 2.7.5 (default, Apr 11 2018, 07:36:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] </code>

I see the error - <code>ERROR! 'k8s_raw' is not a valid attribute for a Play</code>

Comment: Your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50820093/2947502) was closed for a reason. Read the answers under the duplicate questions and fix your issue.

Comment: Here is my yml file - 
- name: Create a k8s namespace
  k8s_raw:
    name: testing
    api_version: v1
    kind: Namespace
    state: present